# Can't Debug Azure JavaScript Function using Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am using VS code first time and trying to create a azure function with JavaScript language.
I followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node).

**Environment:**

- NodeJS v16.x installed
- Azure Functions Extensions installed
- Azure Functions Core Tools 4.x installed

**Problem:**

I created one sample azure function. When running the app with f5 it shows the following error

[image: Error Image1]

I removed extension bundle configuration from the `host.json` and tried again. This time, I got the following error

[image: Error Image2]

Can anyone please help on me this

Update:

**host.json**

```
    {
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
```

Comment: Running it as administrator?

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan you mean vs code in admin mode? sorry not checked. I will check and confirm.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I tried but same result

Answer (score 1):

---

**Here is the workaround I did to run the Azure Functions of JavaScript Stack using Visual Studio Code by following the same documentation given in the question**

**Pre-requisites:**

1. Install ***VS Code*** and Install the ***Azure Account***, ***Azure Functions***, ***Azure Storage***, ***Azurite***, Extension from Extensions Menu and ***Sign-in*** to Azure Account from VS Code.
2. Download and Install ***NodeJS*** Version 14 (and 16 is in preview I guess), Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows

- ***Verify*** the installation from command prompt using the commands `node -v` and `npm -v`.
- If you think, you have installed old NodeJS and NPM versions, go ahead to update them. (Reference: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version and https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade).

3. Install the ***Azure Storage Emulator*** (it is deprecated but still using for local development and testing) from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator) by clicking on the standalone installer.
   -After Installing the Azure Storage Emulator, make sure it is running. If it is shutdown, then run it manually.
   To start the Azure Storage Emulator:

   - Select the  **Start**  button or press the  **Windows**  key.
   - Begin typing  `Azure Storage Emulator`.
   - Select the emulator from the list of displayed applications.
   - Type `Start` > Enter and Close the Window.
4. Install the ***Azure Functions Core Tools*** v3 as well as v4 used for both Old Version and New Version Stack Development from the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#v2) and check the version using `func --versio`n command from command prompt.
5. Install the ***Azure CLI*** from the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) and ***PowerShell Module*** from the [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2).
6. Follow this [prerequisite check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-node?tabs=azure-cli,browser#prerequisite-check) before going to the IDE (VS Code/Visual Studio).

---

#### Steps for running the Azure Functions with/without debugging:

1. Created the workspace folder in the file explorer and opened VS Code from that folder path.
2. Created Azure Functions Project of JavaScript Stack using Azure Functions extension.
   Here is the boilerplate code which is not modified:

**Index.js**

```
module.exports = async  function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

const  name = (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name));

const  responseMessage = name
? "Hello, " + name + ". This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
: "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";

context.res = {
// status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
body:  responseMessage
};
}
```

**local.settings.json**

```
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node"
}
}
```

**host.json**

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
"applicationInsights": {
"samplingSettings": {
"isEnabled": true,
"excludedTypes": "Request"
}
}
},
"extensionBundle": {
"id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
"version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
}
}
```

- No need to remove the extension bundles from `host.json`

**To Run the Function, go to Run Menu > Select either of options `Start Debugging` or `Run without Debugging` and I have run this without starting the VS Code, it runs successful in locally.**

[image]

#### To Debug the Code:

Put a breakpoint at any line of the code and select the `Start Debugging` option from the `Run` Menu

[image]

**Note:**
For the errors like: `A host error has occurred during startup operation`, `Value cannot be null`, few resolution steps were:

- Use ***Azure Storage emulator*** in local development and testing purpose.
- Make Sure You have the ***latest version of Azure Functions Core Tools*** along with old if you have (You can install multiple version of AF Core Tools and use according to the requirement).
- In ***local.settings.json***, value of `AzureWebJobsStorage` is empty by default but if we're using the project locally, it is better to use like `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

**You can download the above project from my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/HariKrishnaRajoli-MT/BasicAzureFunctionJavaScript).**

---

Comment: Thank you. Same way only I created. The only difference is "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true".   I am thinking of any setup issue. I tried from laptop. But the same issue I also got in my desktop... Any problem of install nodejs after install vs code?

Comment: @Akhil, Check and Let me know if any issue comes up and make sure `host.json` is the same as I was given.

Comment: thank you. I created same way only but without any azure webjobsstorage

Comment: Yes @Akhil, You need to install the Node Js, Azure Functions Core Tools, Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator, Microsoft Azure storage explorer for running the Azure Functions in VS Code/Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, you have to install the Azurite extension from Visual Studio code. Reference: https://i.imgur.com/iMbGYlT.png

Comment: I installed all but installed vscode before updating nodejs. Other than that I have installed all

Comment: Thank you . I will install Azurite and confirm

Comment: If you're debugging the code, put a breakpoint in any line of the code and select option Start debugging from Run Menu!

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Could you please share with us the codes from host.json, local.settings.json and index.js you're trying

Comment: I updated the code in the original post

Comment: Hello @Akhil, Any update to the issue?

Comment: Hi @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT no. Same error. I have update the code like u mentioned

Comment: @akhil, How many function triggers are you using? Make sure All your trigger will be in root folder.

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT I used only one which is httptrigger. I just tried my first one with microsoft sample

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Thank you I will check and confirm

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT sure but still working on that.  Your update helped me a lot and I can run in my desktop. But still not working in my laptop. Same error I am getting.

Comment: @Akhil, Uninstall and Re-install the tools and applications once or try updating the tools like VS Code, Azure CLI, PowerShell Modules etc.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT That I am doing now. I did multiple time but looking the environment variables

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I can see that Azure Functions Extension Bundle not added to the user location

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Still I didn't got exact solution for the original error. Looking for that. Surly will update once got

Comment: @Akhil, Did you check with my code given in GitHub Repo on your laptop IDE?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT yes i did that also. So only thinking some infra issue but can't find the reason